# Couchbase query using n1ql from nodejs

Tags: node.js, couchbase, sql++

```
var N1qlQuery = require('couchbase').N1qlQuery;
var couchbase = require("couchbase");
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('host');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('default');
 bucket.enableN1ql('host');



var query = N1qlQuery.fromString('SELECT * from default');
bucket.query(query, function(err, res){
  if (err) {
    console.log('query failed', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('success!', res);
});
```

Not able to query.Getting error as

connect ECONNREFUSED
code: "ECONNREFUSED'
syscall :'connect'

Comment: Connection refused... Have you replaced `'host'` with an actual server address?

Comment: I changed host and "from". Still getting the same error .

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. This seems to be a network connectivity issue. Nothing necessarily related to Node.js or N1QL. Are you positive the server is running and ports are not blocked?

Comment: Hey, as you said port was blocked.I am using default port of 8092.Connection refused error has gone. But now error is ; failed to connect to bucket.

Comment: Okay, so go to port 8091, the admin interface, and make sure there is a bucket by the name of default. I do not think Couchbase Server comes with any buckets setup. You also need a primary key, I think, on that bucket in order to even start using N1QL

Comment: Yeah. That works fine without creating primary index. But it gives error as : Query failed[failed to parse query response as json]